# Debian 6, ports closed anyway

Tags: debian, iptables

I ran all the following commands

> iptables -F
>   iptables -X
>   iptables -t nat -F
>   iptables -t nat -X
>   iptables -t mangle -F
>   iptables -t mangle -X
>   iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
>   iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
>   iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

And all ports are still closed, why? how?
I can only telnet on localhost.

Comment: Did you check if iptables rules are deleted afterwards? Check the output of `iptables -nL` and `iptables -t nat -nL`. It's also possible that iptables is not the reason, but there's just no service listening on the external interface. Check the output of `netstat -ntpl` .

Comment: How do you determine that they are closed? Did you actually install a relevant daemon that listens on a port?

Comment: Now my port 25 is working, but do not answer the telnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in the `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` file:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

And running

`# iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4`

Then run

`# iptables -L -n -v`

to check the result.

Comment: I will try but my server was down, sorry for delay.

Comment: I did that from SSH and now I cant connect, why?

Comment: Ok I got lucky, I dont know how but linux return response 1 hour later automatically, so thanks for answer, but check this link please http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=scan%3a184.171.253.138&run=toolpage

Comment: is 184.171.253.138 an IP associated to one of your interfaces or are you behind a FW?

Comment: This server was located, whit 3 static ips , I have this system working well on VirtualBox, but on virtual box I cant use telnet outside of this server because the virtual box dont give a valid staci debian directly ip. I made a good choice? I Realized a mistake?

Comment: Can you join the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) to discuss the details?

Comment: yes please I am online Stackexchange

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8320/discussion-with-lucas-rodrigues